# VBA Excel Class Library

Tags: vba, excel

For awhile now I have been developing tools for use at work in VBA Excel. It's the best solution for what i need to be done and how to get it done, however my programs now have multiple Classes and Modules which leads to a lot of exporting my classes and importing them again on a new Workbook if necessary.

My question is, how can I package my classes into a library that can be referenced in the same way "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" is referenced. I've looked for topics on this, but I've never quite found any answers that relate to my situation.

I'm using Excel 2016 and I have access to Visual Studio 2017 at home. Any details would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just put all the code in an Add-In (xlam) file instead? Then you wont need to copy your classes into other workbooks.

Comment: You can also make a COM visible dll, if you want to extend your code with .NET. Although using a .xlam file as @braX suggests is a good approach too. Depends on what you want to do

Comment: @braX Thank you, i'm going to try this out